# smoothing mouse movement

Tags: c#, mouse, move, kinect

I'm developing a software to move the mouse based on certain coordinates which i get from a depth image from kinect. but I have 30 frames/second(images/second) and those coordinates changes with every frame so the mouse keeps moving. My question is,Is there a way to smooth the movement of the mouse ?

Comment: Could you provide more information? How much is the jittery movement (large/small)? If it is small - some sort of simple temporal filtering can help. If it is large it probably points to issues with your data/algorithm and cannot be smoothed without rethinking the problem.

Comment: As @ananthonline said - we'd need a LOT more context, and without a doubt some sample code. Sounds interesting though - I like problems like this, get some code up.

Comment: The jitter is  small but what I want is to smooth the movement, like when the mouse should go from a position to another. It shows some discontinuity. I want a way to move it like the normal mouse does (I know the normal mouse has a much higher frequency but is there any way to move my cursor similarly?)

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can start tracking with some parameters that allows you to make move smoother.
 Below is an example code:

```
        var parameters = new TransformSmoothParameters
        {
            Smoothing = 0.2f,
            Correction = 0.0f,
            Prediction = 0.0f,
            JitterRadius = 1.0f,
            MaxDeviationRadius = 0.5f
        };

        this._sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(parameters);
```

You can change `Smoothing`, `Correction`, `Prediction`, `JitterRadius`, and `MaxDeviationRadius` to whatever numbers you want.

Comment: Fixus, this will only work if the OP is tracking the skeleton - not if he is directly using the depth image to calculate the mouse position.

Comment: @ananthonline true that. I should write that. But combining both streams isn`t hard so I thought this is a good thing to write :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure about this but is there a way to map the depth coordinates to a skeleton point and track that one ? if yes please provide me a sample code .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Since you wanted to know about ["mapping depth coordinates to skeleton points"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756772/smoothing-mouse-movement#comment14285602_10758894), you can use the `DepthImageFrame`'s [`MapToSkeletonPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.depthimageframe.maptoskeletonpoint.aspx) which takes the X and Y values of the depth data and then create a `SkeletonPoint`. Example:

```
 SkeletonPoint point = depthFrame.MapToSkeletonPoint(x, y);
```

Hope this helps!